Cannot make guacamole connection direct url for SSH connection
I need to make a direct connection url using Guacamole API in my application to connect to a Linux VM through SSH so that application users can directly connect to the machine by using the url in browser.
This is what i tried:
Step 1
I have a connection created in Guacamole with connectionId: 287 [SSH connection for a Linux RHEL machine]
Then i created this JSON on my machine:
{"username":"","expires":1716440632,"connections":{"287":{"protocol":"SSH","parameters":       {"hostname":"IP OF MY LINUX MACHIE","port":"22","username":"USER","password":"PASSWD"}}}} 

Step 2
Then i encrypted above JSON with key (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/guacamoleclient/
master/extensions/guacamole-auth-json/doc/encrypt-json.sh):
▪ https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/json-auth.html
./encrypt-json.sh HEX_ENCRthen i get Base64 token using the below JSON secret key./encrypt-json.sh 4C0B569E4C96DF157EEE1B65DD0E4D41 auth.json

Step 3
I made this request:
 curl --location 'https://{baseUrl}/api/tokens' \
                --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
                --data-urlencode
                'data=Xirte6W6mrr+a1XyyNH8qgt+LRiyzCy6nckw4KvnXE0/kRjUs3mZj0S6ZctrRr3MPULG
                mqyGMEC4gHWMtReGTdHB+AboJ9CfdqUa3o7LCQbmGigDO9Hd/tQ08gTkQkCPkDYky6
                We+AYDSZeg/HLtFVoqGOwPOwAaeygmLYlkyCvq9GgMbAVKzqS59sZOqtTRJi7LYSAiOexY
                M/LKUUrwO47xbYrLKjIhp4amA5WlhuZIxRMDUcQDr1292Wd/Hzx9TTTzQxshI1hWJMdEq
                6xNsu3ksvGMVBeXm5mheqe31rBJ+2qUHnlzVyAAB90ieNzWnC1hwhcA0TfvVlrmOOog/g
                ipKDknEhPp1K900e8iP1/8JLUHxXeKhtS8AQGim1j1D33wlG+Ey0TSItmLhiJ/FXIKhEpkql1Zo
                '
                o Response :
                {
                "authToken":
                "F0060F333BBAF137B927E42C4AFDD5032FE3E7706EBDFC55286CCBC59D0CFCE9",
                "username": "administrator",
                "dataSource": "json",
                "availableDataSources": [
                "postgresql",
                "postgresql-shared",
                "json"
                ]
                }

Step 4
Use authtoken from above response and append to url as query parameter named
token
https://{baseUrl}/guacamole/#/?token=
                F0060F333BBAF137B927E42C4AFDD5032FE3E7706EBDFC55286C

above is final URL to be called from UI
The above url on browser tries to make connection but it never connects to my machine. However the same machine is being properly getting connected through guacamole console but not thru the above url.
Connection waiting screen

